# Get function return value as argument in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I have a function **written(arg)**

```
function written(arg)
{
for(var i in arg)
console.log(arg[i]);
}
```

which generally expects a string but i want to modify it so that it can take functions as argument. After that change i want to call it like

```
written(function(){return str;})
```

So **my question is** how to extract value of `arg` in `function written` in which it can be a String or a function which return String

Comment: By JSON you mean a JavaScript Object, right?  The question has nothing to do with the JSON standard.

Comment: Add control flows to direct the flow of execution based on the input.  In this case it would be a bidirectional flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check whether the passed parameter is a function, if it is then invoke it to access the json value

```
function written(arg){
    if(typeof arg === 'function'){
        arg = arg();
    }
    for(var i in arg){
        console.log(arg[i]);
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PLHmv/)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that, after checking the argument, to call your function recursively:

```
function written(arg){
    if(typeof arg === 'function'){
        return written.apply(this,[arg()]);
    }
    // Actual body of your function
}
```

Just in case you have higher order functions